# vb.net Strings.StrConv Convert Simplified Chinese to Traditional Chinese shows some "?"

Tags: vb.net

When using Strings.StrConv to convert simplified chinese to traditional chinese, it returns some word(s) as a "?".

```
Dim input as String = "简体中文";
Dim output as String = Strings.StrConv(input, VbStrConv.TraditionalChinese);  
messageBox.show("input[" & input  & "] output[" & output & "]")
```

Expected result:
input[简体中文] output[簡體中文]

Got result:
input[简体中文] output[?體中文]

I only get this problem on convering simplified chinese to traditional chinese, but without problem vise versa.
Could someone help if you know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but that usually indicates that the font in use doesn't understand that particular character. If you look at the actual data in the debugger, does it contain what you expect?

Comment: Try using Unicode hex representation for each character: `ChrW(&H7B80) & ChrW(&H4F53) & ChrW(&H4E2D) & ChrW(&H6587)`. I got the zh-Hant representation properly as in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5abU3p.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It shows the same "?體中文" in debugger. Thanks!

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Your code in fiddle works even if I just put "简体中文" as the input string without converted to hex! Maybe my development environment settings problem. I will check that out! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by putting Simplified Chinese Locale ID to the 3rd parameter of StrConv!

```
Dim input as String = "简体中文";
Dim output as String = Strings.StrConv(input, VbStrConv.TraditionalChinese, 2052);  
messageBox.show("input[" & input  & "] output[" & output & "]")
```

Got result correctly: input[简体中文] output[簡體中文]

LocaleID from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047(WinEmbedded.10).aspx